# Global GOPRIVATE setting in Goland

Tags: go, goland

Is there any way to have the Goland inherit the global environment for the `go get` command? We have lots of private packages and projects on a self-hosted git and we need to have them work with the same GOPRIVATE settings. Unfortunately Goland works with it's completely separated env vars for each project and I can't find any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify GOPRIVATE variable for GoLand globally via *File | New Projects Setup | Preferences/Settings for New Projects | Go | Go modules | Environment*.

Comment: It only affects current project.

Comment: Then you can configure it via _Preferences/Settings | Go | Go Modules_.

Comment: Have you test it for yourself? It's literally the exact same thing, the problem is whenever you make/add a new project to goland it asks you for whole new `env vars`! I don't want to do this! I want Goland to read it (automatically) from the `.bashrc` or sth like that Or make Goland to run `go get` like it runs in normal terminal not a whole separated thing.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it and my original message is how to configure `GOPRIVATE` variable or another one for new projects in GoLand. Why this approach is not working in your case?

Comment: As I mentioned in the Question, Goland asks for totally new GOPRIVATE on each project and doesn't sync itself with system env.

Comment: So, do I get it right that you have a different `GOPRIVATE` variable for each new project?

Comment: Nope, I have git.example.com/* in GOPRIVATE and it's the same for all of my projects as my git is self-hosted and its repos are all private

Comment: So, have you tried to specify that environment variable globally inside GoLand? Why wouldn't it work in your case?

Comment: That's the point, apperantly there isn't any way to define global env vars in GoLand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you are looking for. You can set it in the `makefile` or `build`. Also instead of exporting via bash you can use this command. This sets it global. To test make another go project after setting it and run: go env

```golang
go env -w GOPRIVATE=hq-stash.yourcorp.net

//After Setting make project else where and test
go env 

//output: 
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/you/.go"
GOPRIVATE="hq-stash.yourcorp.net"
```